# AngularJS directive to update DOM

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to write a directive that change an image depending on the attribute value "name". The image is shown but it doesn't update when the "name" attribute changes.

HTML:

```
<img test name="{{finder.name}}"
```

JS:

```
.directive("test", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            name: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("name", function(value) {
                if (angular.isDefined(value))
                    var replaceName = value.replace(/[ \/]+/g, "_")
                        .toLowerCase();
                var tag = '<img src="/images/banner_' + 
                        replaceName + '.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>'
                element.replaceWith(tag);
            })
        }}}
    );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did on my simple image directive.. to generate dynamic image source..

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // this will replace the value of your image source
        var setImagrSRC = function() {
            element.attr('src','some source value here..')
        }

        // this will observe if there is changes on your name directive
        // and will trigger the function setImageSRC above
        attrs.$observe('name',setImageSRC);

 }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you overwrite the element with the new element with that `replaceWith` method. Your directive will destroyed with it. Don't replace the element, just replace the attribute :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch('name', function(value){
        ...
        var imageUrl = value.replace(...);
        element.attr('src', imageUrl);
    });
}
```